# Dynamic width of a table

Tags: html, css

I have a simple div, here the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Head</title>
<style>
div.ex {
    height:700px;
    width:150px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
    text_color:#ffffff;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ex">

</div>
</body>
```

Now, I have a table, and  I want to use all the space just for that. How can I do it?

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML that you're using, as well as the CSS of the parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got you properly try this...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Head</title>
<style>
div.ex {
    height:700px;
    width:150px;
    <!--padding:10px;-->
    border:1px solid gray;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
    text_color:#ffffff;

}
table{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="ex">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            test
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Since, entire div space is to be used so remove padding from div..